# Is the single underscore "_" a built-in variable in Python?

Tags: python

I don't understand what this single underscore means. Is it a magic variable? I can't see it in locals() and globals().

```
>>> 'abc'
'abc'
>>> len(_)
3
>>>
```

Comment: Related post - [Finding a list of all double-underscore variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8920341/465053)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In the standard Python REPL, `_` represents the last returned value -- at the point where you called `len(_)`, `_` was the value `'abc'`.

For example:

```
>>> 10
10
>>> _
10
>>> _ + 5
15
>>> _ + 5
20
```

This is handled by [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook), and the `_` variable goes in the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) namespace with things like `int` and `sum`, which is why you couldn't find it in `globals()`.

Note that there is no such functionality within Python *scripts*.  In a script, `_` has no special meaning and will not be automatically set to the value produced by the previous statement.

Also, beware of reassigning `_` in the REPL if you want to use it like above!

```
>>> _ = "underscore"
>>> 10
10
>>> _ + 5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    _ + 5
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

This creates a global variable that hides the `_` variable in the built-ins. To undo the assignment (and remove the `_` from globals), you'll have to:

```
>>> del _
```

then the functionality will be back to normal (the `builtins._` will be visible again).

Comment: FYI: REPL is short for Read-Eval-Print Loop.  As always, wikipedia has more info if you want it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop

Comment: What is a "run-of-the-mill identifier"? Quick search resulted in "merely average; commonplace; mediocre" - what does this mean regarding "_" in python scripts?

Comment: FYI - **A word of caution** : The `_` variable should be treated as read-only by the user. Don’t explicitly assign a value to it — you would create an independent local variable with the same name masking the built-in variable with its magic behavior.

Answer (score 18):

Why you can't see it? It is in `__builtins__`

```
>>> __builtins__._ is _
True
```

So it's neither global nor local. <sup>1</sup>

And where does this assignment happen? `sys.displayhook`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys.displayhook)
Help on built-in function displayhook in module sys:

displayhook(...)
    displayhook(object) -> None

    Print an object to sys.stdout and also save it in __builtin__.
```

<sup>1</sup> 2012 Edit : I'd call it *"superglobal"* since `__builtin__`'s members are available everywhere, in any module.

Comment: Why is something that is only usable in the REPL but not in scripts placed in __builtin__?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, we are using _ in Python to bind a ugettext function.

Comment: this is also true, but only for Python Applications. `gettext.install` will bind to `__builtins__._`, so that it is available without importing in all of the application; thus the same kind of "magic" name.