# Is it possible to use 'else' in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is the code I was trying to turn into a list comprehension:

```
table = ''
for index in xrange(256):
    if index in ords_to_keep:
        table += chr(index)
    else:
        table += replace_with
```

Is there a way to add the else statement to this comprehension?

```
table = ''.join(chr(index) for index in xrange(15) if index in ords_to_keep)
```

Answer (score 449, accepted):

The syntax `a if b else c` is a ternary operator in Python that evaluates to `a` if the condition `b` is true - otherwise, it evaluates to `c`. It can be used in comprehension statements:

```
>>> [a if a else 2 for a in [0,1,0,3]]
[2, 1, 2, 3]
```

So for your example,

```
table = ''.join(chr(index) if index in ords_to_keep else replace_with
                for index in xrange(15))
```

Comment: Also note, that the `else` is necessary and cannot be ommited, because a resulting value is always required.

Comment: The code within join(), is that list comprehension when there is no bracket? Or is that a generator expression and join takes that as argument just fine?

Comment: @huggie it's a generator expression, and `join` happily takes a generator or any other iterable.

Comment: Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: `[a if a else 2 for a in [0,1,0,3]]` but `[a for a in [0,1,0,3] if a]`. `[a for a if a in [0,1,0,3]]` is a syntax error. List comprehensions are great, but the order sometimes can be confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: @EricDuminil It is not confusing. Instead, your `for` is not complete. And `if a in [0,1,0,3]` would be interpreted as expected but different from what you intended. `[a for a in [0,1,0,3] if a in [1,3]]` would be closer.

Comment: @unndreay I wrote this comment a long time ago, at the beginning of my Python journey. What I found confusing is that `if` is left of `for` in one case (with `else`) and right of it with `else`. So I guess my proposal should have been `[a if a for a in [0,1,0,3]]`. It might not be very readable, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil No offense :-), I just wanted to clarify a bit in case someone get's lost.

Answer (score 24):

To use the `else` in list comprehensions in python programming you can try out the below snippet. This would resolve your problem, the snippet is tested on python 2.7 and python 3.5.

```
obj = ["Even" if i%2==0 else "Odd" for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want an `else` you don't want to filter the list comprehension, you want it to iterate over every value. You can use `true-value if cond else false-value` as the statement instead, and remove the filter from the end:

```
table = ''.join(chr(index) if index in ords_to_keep else replace_with for index in xrange(15))
```

Answer (score 18):

**Yes**, `else` can be used in Python inside a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension)  with a [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) ("ternary operator"):

```
>>> [("A" if b=="e" else "c") for b in "comprehension"]
['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'A', 'c', 'A', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Here, the parentheses "()" are just to emphasize the conditional expression, they are not necessarily required ([Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

Additionaly, several expressions can be nested, resulting in more `else`s and harder to read code:

```
>>> ["A" if b=="e" else "d" if True else "x" for b in "comprehension"]
['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'A', 'd', 'A', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']
>>>
```

On a related note, a comprehension can also contain its own `if` condition(s) at the end:

```
>>> ["A" if b=="e" else "c" for b in "comprehension" if False]
[]
>>> ["A" if b=="e" else "c" for b in "comprehension" if "comprehension".index(b)%2]
['c', 'c', 'A', 'A', 'c', 'c']
```

Condition**s**? Yes, multiple `if`s are possible, and actually multiple `for`s, too:

```
>>> [i for i in range(3) for _ in range(3)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
>>> [i for i in range(3) if i for _ in range(3) if _ if True if True]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

(The single underscore `_` is a valid variable name ([identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)) in Python, used here just to show it's *not actually used*. It has a [special meaning in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-the-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python))

Using this for an additional conditional expression is possible, but of  no real use:

```
>>> [i for i in range(3)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> [i for i in range(3) if i]
[1, 2]
>>> [i for i in range(3) if (True if i else False)]
[1, 2]
```

Comprehensions can also be nested to create "multi-dimensional" lists ("arrays"):

```
>>> [[i for j in range(i)] for i in range(3)]
[[], [1], [2, 2]]
```

---

Last but not least, a comprehension is not limited to creating a `list`, i.e. `else` and `if` can also be used the same way in a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) comprehension:

```
>>> {i for i in "set comprehension"}
{'o', 'p', 'm', 'n', 'c', 'r', 'i', 't', 'h', 'e', 's', ' '}
```

and a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in [("key","value"), ("dict","comprehension")]}
{'key': 'value', 'dict': 'comprehension'}
```

The same syntax is also used for [Generator Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> for g in ("a" if b else "c" for b in "generator"):
...     print(g, end="")
...
aaaaaaaaa>>>
```

which can be used to create a `tuple` ([there is no tuple comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python)).

---

Further reading:

- The [Python Tutorial on Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

  - [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
  - [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)
  - [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

> Also, would I be right in concluding that a list comprehension is the most efficient way to do this?

Maybe. List comprehensions are not inherently computationally efficient. It is still running in linear time.

From my personal experience:
I have significantly reduced computation time when dealing with large data sets by replacing list comprehensions (specifically nested ones) with for-loop/list-appending type structures you have above. In this application I doubt you will notice a difference.

Comment: woops, i meant to ask about the join method vs. += on a string.

Comment: Interesting. This (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed#Takeadvantageofinterpreteroptimizations) says otherwise.

Comment: @Josh: in older version of Python, the join() method is vastly superior.  Newer versions of the interpreter attempt to optimize the += method, but I'm not sure how well this works.  I almost always just use the join() method.

Answer (score 1):

Great answers, but just wanted to mention a gotcha that "pass" keyword will not work in the if/else part of the list-comprehension (as posted in the examples mentioned above).

```
#works
list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
newlist2 = [x if x > 30 else x**2 for x in list1 ]
print(newlist2, type(newlist2))

#but this WONT work
list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
newlist2 = [x if x > 30 else pass for x in list1 ]
print(newlist2, type(newlist2))
```

This is tried and tested on python 3.4.
Error is as below:

```
newlist2 = [x if x > 30 else pass for x in list1 ]                                    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, try to avoid pass-es in list comprehensions

Comment: The if/else construct is just an expression as far as the list comprehension is concerned. If you want to leave items out, you need to put your expression in place of `expr2` here  `[expr1 for x in list1 if expr2]`

Comment: Well pass works in a normal if else block , to me, that implies that it would work everywhere else too. But not so in list comprehensions.

Comment: But this isn't a normal if/else block. It's [an expression](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator). You can't use elif in there either.