# 'else' statement in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I've got a variable that could either be a string or a tuple (I don't know ahead of time) and I need to work with it as a list.

Essentially, I want to transform the following into a list comprehension.

```
variable = 'id'
final = []
if isinstance(variable, str):
    final.append(variable)
elif isinstance(variable, tuple):
    final = list(variable)
```

I was thinking something along the lines of the following (which gives me a syntax error).

```
final = [var for var in variable if isinstance(variable, tuple) else variable]
```

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension) but it's not the same because the asker could use the `for` loop at the end; mine only applies if it's a tuple.

**NOTE:** I would like the list comprehension to work if I use `isinstance(variable, list)` as well as the `tuple` one.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a string or a tuple? why can't it be unicode or a list?

Comment: I'm not sure how a list comprehension would be useful here, because the code you have doesn't create a list by iteration. You don't even have a `for` loop.

Comment: The code I have doesn't require a for loop. But if I use the `list(variable` in the list comprehension, it creates a list within a list which isn't what I want _(Although I noticed @Matthew's answer provides a way around it)_. And @Aaron: I don't _need_ it to be a string or a tuple. It's given to me in that format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
final = [variable] if isinstance(variable, str) else list(variable)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rearrange it a bit.

```
final = [var if isinstance(variable, tuple) else variable for var in variable]
```

Or maybe I misunderstood and you really want

```
final = variable if not isinstance(variable, tuple) else [var for var in variable]
```

Comment: This will give `['id', 'id']` for the examples, since it includes one reference to the string for every letter.

Comment: Thanks! Your second one seems to be what I want. I accepted Matthew's because it was a tad shorter and simpler (because he did `list(variable)` rather than `[var for var in variable]` although they amount to the same thing.)