# if and else for list comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

y = [1 for z in x if z > 0]

#WANT TO DO
#y = [1 for z in x if z > 0 else 0]
```

I want to do both an `if` statement and an `else` statement within a list comprehension in Python. How can I do this?

I figured out `y = [int(bool(z)) for z in x]`, but i was wondering if you could do both an `if` and an `else` statement in a list comprehension.

Comment: Do you mean `[1 if z > 0 else 0 for z in x]`? The expression on the right-hand side of the `for foo in bar` is for *filtering*, on the left-hand side is for *mapping*.

Comment: Better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2951701/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on the left-hand side of the list comprehension (that is, the statement before the `for` keyword:

```
y = [1 if z > 0 else 0 for z in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible here is an example:

```
y = [1 if z > 0 else 'test' for z in x ]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension) thread also provides a few more details about it.

Comment: That *"thread"* is a clear duplicate, please flag as such.