# Multiply sub items of only lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a data structure like this

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], {9,2,5,8,7}, (7, 4, 8, 6)]
```

One big list containing lists, sets, and tuples.

I want to multiply everything inside a list by 3, but not the things inside tuple or set. Output should be:

```
[[3,6,9,12,15], {9,2,5,8,7}, (7, 4, 8, 6)]
```

The items inside the list all got multiplied by 3, rest remain unchanged.

I have tried this:

```
l = [[2,6,9,13,15], {9,2,5,8,7}, (7, 4, 8, 6)]
newList = [[subitem*3 for subitem in subList ] for subList in l]
print(newList)
```

But this gives me bad output:

```
[[3, 6, 9, 12, 15], [24, 27, 6, 15, 21], [21, 12, 24, 18]]
```

The list is good, but the set and tuple need to remain unchanged, they shouldn't be converted to list either. I want output exactly like I have shown previously.

Thanks!

Comment: Then add a condition and check if subList is an instance of `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this comprehension pattern: `[x if a else b for x in lst]`:

```
new_list = [[3*y for y in x] if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in l]
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension) for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize the solution was this simple. Apologies. I'll accept this one since it was posted first. (can't accept yet, have to wait 5 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided was so close, all you need to do is add a check for if the subList is a list, then if so multiply else leave alone.

```
l = [[2,6,9,13,15], {9,2,5,8,7}, (7, 4, 8, 6)]
newList = [[subitem*3 for subitem in subList ] if type(subList) is list else subList for subList in l]
print(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newList = [[subitem*3 for subitem in subList ] if isinstance(subList, list) else subList for subList in l]
```

This can be an option!