# (Python) Split dictionary in two based on a property

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to split a dictionary in two based on whether any of an array of strings is present in a property within the main dictionary. Currently I can achieve this with two separate dictionary comprehensions (below), but is there a more efficient way to do this with only one line/dictionary comprehension?

```
included = {k:v for k,v in users.items() if not any(x.lower() in v["name"].lower() for x in EXCLUDED_USERS)}
excluded = {k:v for k,v in users.items() if any(x.lower() in v["name"].lower() for x in EXCLUDED_USERS)}
```

**EDIT**

`EXCLUDED_USERS` contains a list of patterns.

Comment: Why don't you create an array/dict with 2 elements and direct the elements into the right place based on the condition?

Comment: @LaurIvan you mean one dictionary with two keys, one for included and one for excluded?

Comment: What's in `EXCLUDED_USERS`?  Complete usernames or username patterns?

Comment: EXCLUDED_USERS is a list of patterns

Comment: I have posted a possible 1 line solution

Comment: @Sinfieldd can you post sample users dict so I can check it better?

Comment: @Sinfieldd yes, similar to what Eric proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line solution (with `lower_excluded_users` which I couldn't resist making)

```
included, excluded = dict(), dict()

# ssly, you don't have to do this everytime
lower_excluded_users = [x.lower() for x in EXCLUDED_USERS]

# and now the one-line answer using if-else-for construct with
# v substituted by D[k]. And instead of using `for k, v in dicn.items()`
# I have used [... for aKey in dicn.keys()]

[ excluded.update({aKey: users[aKey]}) \
    if any(x in users[aKey]["name"].lower() for x in lower_excluded_users) \
    else \
    included.update({aKey: users[aKey]}) \
    for aKey in users.keys()
]
```

Or one without beautification:

```
[excluded.update({aKey: users[aKey]}) if any(x in users[aKey]["name"].lower() for x in lower_excluded_users) else included.update({aKey: users[aKey]}) for aKey in users.keys()]
```

Comment: You only use a list comprehension as a for loop, without caring for the result of the comprehension. It's less readable and doesn't bring any advantage IMHO. Note : I didn't downvote.

Comment: @EricDuminil - actually, calling a function within a list/dict comprehension block would be marginally faster (<5%) at the expense of memory (around 8MB for each 1M loop provided that the function returns `None`). It will also make your code notoriously hard to read and debug.

Comment: It's not about speed or readability, OP expects a one liner. That's what I give. Everyone knows what makes Python a darling language

Comment: He's right, I said a one liner and this accomplishes that

Comment: @Sinfieldd :: Umm... She?

Comment: Humblest apologies ☺

Answer (score 5):

This solution is more verbose, but it should be more efficient and possibly more readable:

```
included = {}
excluded = {}

lower_excluded_users = [x.lower() for x in EXCLUDED_USERS]

for k,v in users.items():
    if any(x in v["name"].lower() for x in lower_excluded_users):
        excluded[k] = v
    else:
        included[k] = v
```

I don't think it can be done with one single comprehension. It's possible to use [a ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension) inside the `k:v` statement, it's not possible to use `else` after the `if` in a `{k:v for k,v in users.items() if k ...}` pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I had considered this, but I was trying to achieve it with one dictionary comprehension