# Why is else required in if statements when defining a list of items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

When defining a list of items (i.e. not actual list comprehensions), why do you need an else statement to accompany any if statements? For example, using Python 3.7 say that we have some condition which could be true or false, and we want to include an element in a list if the condition is true, and not include it if it's false.

```
condition = False
lyst = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition]
```

I would expect it to assign ['a', 'b'] to lyst, but it throws a syntax error. It works if we include an else statement:

```
lyst = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else 'd']
```

But now the result is that `lyst = ['a', 'b', 'd']`
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-python-list-comprehension), user Plankton's answer further specifies that you can't use a "pass" in the else statement. My question is *why* the else statement is required? Is it so that the list that gets created is guaranteed to have the number of items expected? If so, this strikes me as not very pythonic.

This is particularly weird because you *can* have if statements without else statements in actual list comprehensions e.g.:

```
post = [x for x in range(10) if x > 5]
# equivalent to: post = [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I realize a list comprehension is totally different functionality. Please remember that my question is *why* you can't use an if statement without an else in a list literal? Does this limitation avoid some issue I'm not aware of?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c']` notation is not a list comprehension.

Comment: `x if cond else y` in Python is an expression. It must have a value regardless of whether the condition is true or false. That's why you always must provide an alternative. You confuse the expression with the `if cond: do_somethig` statement.

Comment: [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html)

Comment: `if condition else 'd'` is a conditional expression. In some ways it's _similar_ to the `if` expression permitted in a comprehension, but it's not the same. And both of those are different to an `if... elif... else` compound statement.

Comment: This is a *very* general question, leading into the tutorial level (off-topic).  Each of the techniques you've mentioned works differently, as you're finding.  When to use each depends entirely on what you're trying to do at the time.

Comment: @user2357112 good point, I had this worded correctly in the actual question, but not in the title. Fixing now...

Comment: It would be nice if Python 3 still had a nice simple term for "list displays that aren't comprehensions" (besides the hopelessly technical `starred_list` from the grammar).

Comment: FWIW, you _could_ do `lyst = ['a', 'b'] + (['c'] if condition else [])`

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the conditional expression `a if b else c` with the syntax for a list comprehension, which *requires* a `for ... in ...` clause that can have an *optional* `if` (but no `else`).

1. The expression

   ```
   ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition]
   ```

   is a syntax error, because it's not a list comprehension (no `for`), and `c if condition` is not a valid expression (no `else`).
2. The expression

   ```
   ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else 'd']
   ```

   is a valid list *literal*, consisting of the values `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c' if condition else 'd'` (which evaluates to either `'c'` or `'d'` depending on the value of `condition`).
3. The expression

   ```
   [x for x in range(10) if x > 5]
   ```

   is a list comprehension, with `if x > 5` being a filter applied to the value of `x` each time you take a value from `range(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with list-comprehensions. It's purely about lists, and how to create one using list-literals.

And a list literal is comprised of an opening bracket, and a list of expressions separated by commas.

So in your case, your 'a' and 'b' are expressions (string literals). However 'c' if condition' is not an expression. It's a half-backed if-STATEMENT (much different beast)!

But as ternary operators (x if c else y) are expressions, you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

`['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else 'd']` is interpreted as `['a', 'b', ('c' if condition else 'd')]`. It's not a list comprehension, you're just creating a literal list.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments, your snippet is not list comprehension. You are creating a list with one of the elements as an expression.

```
condition = False
list = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else None]
```

With you example of `list = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition]` (which will fail) you might as well do any of the following:

## Add c conditionally

```
condition = False
list = ['a', 'b']
if condition:
    list.append('c')
```

## Use list comprehension to remove `None` values

```
condition = False
list = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else None]
final_list = [i for i in list if i is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two seperate language features here: ternaries ([conditional expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)) and [filtering](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/).

Ternary:

```
x = 1 if 5 == 5 else 2
#1
```

Filtering:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = [i for i in l if i < 3]
#[1,2,3]
```

---

These are the only two syntactical features you are using, just that you are confusing yourself by using a ternary inside a list definition:

```
l = [1,2,3 if 5 == 5 else 4]
```

see how this is equivalent to:

```
x = 3 if 5 == 5 else 4
l = [1,2,x]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a list comprehension. It's a list with 3 values. The problem is, your 3rd value is `'c' if condition`. That's not a valid *value* in python. It has nothing to do with lists. You could not write `x = 'c' if condition` either. On the other hand, the ternary `if-else` which you are using on the second example is a valid value, and that's why it gets accepted.

Answer (score -2):

I believe if you want your list to be `['a', 'b', 'c']` or `['a', 'b'] then you put the if statement outside as follows:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c' if condition else None]
```

This isn't a list comprehension (above): in list comprehensions there is some loop and a single `if` that acts as a filter. Your code is a conditional (ternary) expression which must be evaluated to produce a result.

Comment: OP posted expected output: `['a', 'b', 'c']` or `['a', 'b']`, and  the code you posted does not output that.

Comment: Your new edit now outputs `['a', 'b', None]` for `condition == False`

Comment: At any rate, I don't think this questions is really _"How do I do X"_ so much as _"Why can't I use X in this way?"_

Comment: Which I have tried to answer by giving some information about list comps and conditional expressions

Comment: That is true, but why post a code example that doesn't even do what the OP has asked?