# I am trying to find out the result shown below with list comprehension:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find out the result shown below with list comprehension:

```py
def X(numbers):
    result = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i > 5:
            result.append('higher')
        else:
            result.append('lower')
        
    return result

numbers=[8,3,7]
assignment_02a(numbers)
```

Answer:`['higher', 'lower', 'higher']`

I have tried this code:

```
[i>5 for i in range(4,8) ]
```

I got this: `[False, False, True, True]`

I expect output to be: `['lower', 'lower', 'higher', 'higher']`

Comment: Next time please do a little research in SO, there are tons of examples with list comprehension, I`m sure you could come up with your own solution...  [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-list-comprehension) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your list comp function is only doing a test for higher/lower but not substituting the result. You could do this in a number of ways but in keeping with the spirit of things you could deference the string from a map.

```
[{True: "Higher", False: "Lower"}[i>5] for i in range(4,8)]
```

you could use a `map` function with a `lambda` to get fancy but this should illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-list-comprehension) there you can find solution for this problem if you read it, carefully.

```py
number = [8,3,7]
numbers = ["Higher" if i>=5 else "Lower" for i in number]
print(numbers)
```

Output:`['Higher', 'Lower', 'Higher']`

Or with range as you asked:

```py
numbers = ["Higher" if i>5 else "Lower" for i in range(4,8)]
print(numbers)
```

Output: `['Lower', 'Lower', 'Higher', 'Higher']`

Comment: Alternatively one can instead conditional expression use indexing:  [["Lower", "Higher"][i>5] for i in range(4,8)]

Comment: Yes, that is one more solution... I agree.

Answer (score 0):

```py
[{True:'higher', Talse:'lower'}[i>5] for i in range(4,8)]
```

if you're getting `True` or `False` then simply use those values with a dictionary. this means that:

- If i > 5 then look in the dict and find that `True` returns `'higher'`
- If i < 5 then look in the dict and find that `False` returns `'lower'`

`[i>5 for i in range(4,8) ]` returns whether or not `i > 5`. If we use a dict then `True` relates to `'higher'` so we return it and `False` relates to `'lower'` so we return that.

Comment: python uses capitalised True and False

Comment: sorry, i've programming in Go and C# and JavaScript for months now