# Syntax error in Python for-if list comprehension loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, syntax-error, list-comprehension

Leaving out the lead-up and data to the following because it looks like an error in how the list comprehension is written. It is meant to cycle through a list `l` of `pandas DataFrame`s and `Series`, and label them based on whether they are two dimensional (both index and columns) or one dimensional (index only). Why the error (even if a close the line-break)?

```
[pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels) for A in l 
            if type(A) is pd.DataFrame else pd.Series(A, index=labels)]
```

results in

```
    if type(A) is pd.DataFrame else pd.Series(A, index=tickers)]
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: the filter clause is only `if` in a list comprehension. What you are actually trying to do is use a conditional expression in the main clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `for A in l` to the end of your statement.

```
[pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels) if type(A) is pd.DataFrame else pd.Series(A, index=labels) for A in l]
```

See: [Is it possible to use 'else' in a list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951701/is-it-possible-to-use-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0):

Is you issue is not due to the is.
Maybe try with isinstance(type(A) , pd.DataFrame)
Another point is the order of your list compréhension if think it should be

```
[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]
```

So you can try

```
[pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels) if isinstance(type(A) , pd.DataFrame) else pd.Series(A, index=labels) for A in l ]
```