# How do I removes \n founds between double quotes from a string?

Tags: python, string

Good day,

I am totally new to Python and I am trying to do something with string.

I would like to remove any `\n` characters found between double quotes ( `"` ) **only**, from a given string :

`str = "foo,bar,\n\"hihi\",\"hi\nhi\""`

The desired output must be:

```
foo,bar
"hihi", "hihi"
```

**Edit:**

The desired output must be similar to that string:
`after = "foo,bar,\n\"hihi\",\"hihi\""`

Any tips?

Comment: Arguably everything in your string is between double quotes, so what do you mean by "between double quotes"?  Between the escaped double quotes (i.e. with backslashes ('\') in front of them)?

Comment: @GreenMatt: Foo,bar isn't double quoted.

Comment: @GreenMatt: Yes I believe I must rely on regexp there. Any ideas? I am not a huge regexp guru here...

Comment: @Cybrix: you don't, see my answer.

Comment: @Cybrix:  My first comment wasn't clear, sorry.  I was trying to make the point that there are double quote around the whole string, so your question wasn't clear (at least to me) on the first reading.  One way to deal with that would have been to enclose your string in single quotes.  And you now have a few suggestions to choose from, including one using a regex.  Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple stateful filter will do the trick.

```
in_string  = False
input_str  = 'foo,bar,\n"hihi","hi\nhi"'
output_str = ''

for ch in input_str:
    if ch == '"': in_string = not in_string
    if ch == '\n' and in_string: continue
    output_str += ch

print output_str
```

Comment: Since I'm a total newbie to Python and your code is the only one that works: Thank you, answer accepted.

Comment: It's the least efficient solution on this page. Think 40MB of data without any double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
def removenewlines(s):
    inquotes = False
    result = []

    for chunk in s.split("\""):
        if inquotes: chunk.replace("\n", "")
        result.append(chunk)
        inquotes = not inquotes

    return "\"".join(result)
```

Comment: printing the original string will still cause a newline on the second `\n`.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I need to get rid: replacing every `'\n'` with nothing `''`. But only those that are found inside the `""`.

Comment: It is an obvious solution, isn't it. Strings are immutable (even though CPython optimises +=), so it must be `result += ch`, though, or `result = []` and then join.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> str = "foo,bar,\n\"hihi\",\"hi\nhi\""
>>> re.sub(r'".*?"', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('\n',''), str, flags=re.S)
'foo,bar,\n"hihi","hihi"'
>>>
```

Short explanation:

1. re.sub is a substitution engine. It takes a regular expression, a substitution function or expression, a string to work on, and other options.
2. The regular expression ".*?" catches strings in double quotes that don't in themselves contain other double quotes (it has a small bug, because it wouldn't catch strings which contain escaped double-quotes).
3. lambda x: ... is an expression which can be used wherever a function can be used.
4. The substitution engine calls the function with the match object.
   x.group(0) is "the whole matched string", which also includes the double quotes.
   x.group(0) is the matched string with '\n' substituted for ''.
5. The flag re.S tells re.sub that '\n' is a valid character to catch with a dot.

Personally I find longer functions that say the same thing more tiring and less readable, in the same way that in C I would prefer `i++` to `i = i + 1`. It's all about what one is used to reading.

Comment: +1, but it needs explanation, especially since the OP is new to Python.

Comment: Ugh, I would prefer a 6 line function than this unreadable mess.

Comment: Eli Collins wrote essentially the same, using an explicit function rather than a lambda expression. Why do you think that this is unreadable? re.sub has many option for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Quick note: Python strings can use `''` or `""` as delimiters, so it's common practice to use one when the other is inside your string, for readability. Eg: `'foo,bar,\n"hihi","hi\nhi"'`. On to the question...

You probably want the python regexp module: [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).
In particular, the substitution function is what you want here. There are a bunch of ways to do it, but one quick option is to use a regexp that identifies the `""` substrings, then calls a helper function to strip any `\n` out of them...

```
import re
def helper(match):
    return match.group().replace("\n","")
input = 'foo,bar,\n"hihi","hi\nhi"'
result = re.sub('(".*?")', helper, input, flags=re.S)
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works (assuming that quotes are correctly balanced):

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"""(?x) # verbose regex
    \n        # Match a newline
    (?!       # only if it is not followed by
     (?: 
      [^"]*"  # an even number of quotes
      [^"]*"  # (and any other non-quote characters)
     )*       # (yes, zero counts, too)
     [^"]*
     \z       # until the end of the string.
    )""", 
    "", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

Break the CSV data into columns.

```
>>> m=re.findall(r'(".*?"|[^"]*?)(,\s*|\Z)',s,re.M|re.S)
>>> m
[('foo', ','), ('bar', ',\n'), ('"hihi"', ','), ('"hi\nhi"', ''), ('', '')]
```

Replace just the field instances of '\n' with ''.

```
>>> [ field.replace('\n','') + sep for field,sep in m ]
['foo,', 'bar,\n', '"hihi",', '"hihi"', '']
```

Reassemble the resulting stuff (if that's really the point.)

```
>>> "".join(_)
'foo,bar,\n"hihi","hihi"'
```

Comment: "I can't make it work".  Really?  Anything *specific*?  An error message?  A value for `m` or something specific that could be used for debugging?  Any hint at all?

Comment: It works in the shell. I will keep you updated because I can't make it work in my source where `s` is a much bigger string.

Comment: Something like: `"".join(_) NameError: global name '_' is not defined`. Again, working perfectly in the shell but not in my script.

Comment: @Cybrix: Read this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python.  It's a short cut that only works in interactive Python.  You have to use proper assignment and a proper variable when writing a script.