# Variable assigned to the last executed line?

Tags: python, interpreter

I just found something weird in the Python interpreter. Let me show you:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> _
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_' is not defined
>>> 5 + 4
9
>>> _
9
>>> 'Hello world'
'Hello world'
>>> _
'Hello world'
>>> type(3.5)
<type 'float'>
>>> _
<type 'float'>
```

You can try this in your interpreter; there are no tricks at work here!

Is the result of the last executed line being assigned to a variable named `_`?

Does anybody know something about it? Is there any documentation about it? In which situation could it be useful?

Comment: I thought everybody knew (and used) that...

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python

Comment: search for underscore and python at stackoverflow

Comment: I think that was really unfair ...

Comment: Well, it's not really a _question_. SO is a _question_ and _answer_ site. If you had asked "Where do I find the implementation of the feature `_` in the Python interpreter?" or something similar, it might have survived.

Comment: aren't there 3 questions in the last line?

Comment: Well, I voted to close as exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python  so I'm not sure why my name's in the list for 'closed as not a real question'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look here [Reserved identifiers python](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

> The special identifier _ is used in the interactive interpreter to
>   store the result of the last evaluation; it is stored in the
>   **builtin** module.

This behavior can be found on haskell's interactive environment `ghci` also. Here instead of `_` use `it`.

```
Prelude> 2+2
4
Prelude> it
4
```

Answer (score 3):

It's useful when exploring in the interactive interpreter, when you forgot to assign a name to some returned object, you can grab a reference to it using `x = _`.  Note that in `ipython` you also have `__` for the second-to-last returned, and `___` is the third-to-last.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a big secret (for example, you can find it mentioned in [Code Like a Pythonista](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#interactive)) but true, it's not well known.  It could be useful when you're doing a lot of work at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Per
[What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/underscore-in-python)

There are three main uses for `_`. One is "real" (the usage you discovered), and the other two are conventions.

Interesting... I never knew!

Comment: __ is not only convention. 
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables