# What is the reason python handles locals() this way (in pairs)?

Tags: python

Get this simple python code, same matching with re.compile instance.
I noticed that even though I am using the very same value, it creates two instances, and repeats them accordingly.

I wonder if one can tell the reason for this behavior,

- Why does it create the second instance at all?
- Why only two?
- And why each time picked the other one and not randomly?

**the CLI code:**

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> rec = re.compile("(?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\s|$)")
>>>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb238>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb238>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb238>
>>> rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
```

**Edit:**

As [@kimvais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180174/kimvais) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160431/9296), the reason lays in the `_` which holds the latest assignment.
see, if you not assigning, rather printing, it is the same one, all the time.

```
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
>>> print rec.match('www.example.com')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb1d0>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My *guess* is that this has something to do with the [return value being assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python) to underscore  (`_`) internally in the interactive python shell - i.e. since `_` is pointing to `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x23cb238>` 'til the next `rec.match` is completed the same local cannot be reused until `_` points to somewhere else and the old one can be recycled.

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest. +1. Try putting the commands in a script and running that; then the allocator actually reuses the address (on my Linux box at least).

Comment: that *sounds* like the right answer, I'll be waiting for some more references before marking this answer as the **correct** one.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is an implementation detail.  You actually had 6 unique instances of the `<_sre.SRE_MATCH>` object.

Since you made no explicit references to them, the garbage collector would free them in due time, allowing that same memory location to be re-used.

The `0x23cb1d0` is essentially the memory location of the object, not a GUID.

Try assigning these to a local variable, and you will see that since they are not garbage collected, new memory locations will be used for each instance.

Comment: but that still not explaining why the exact same two rare used repeatedly, does it?