# Behaviour of __del__ on unassigned python object

Tags: python, reference-counting, del

First ever question, sorry if it's been asked before - I did search but I couldn't find anything that seemed to answer it.

I have been trying to understand the behaviour of python's `__del__` method, as I need it to perform some cleanup on wrapped C code.

My understanding of `__del__` is that is is called when an object's reference count reaches zero, not when `del` is called on an object reference. This led me to believe that instantiating an object without assignment would call `__init__` then `__del__` immediately after, but this doesn't seem to be the case, as the following code demonstrates:

```
class Foo():
   def __init__(self):
      print "Hello"
   def __del__(self):
      print "Goodbye"

Foo()
Hello
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x7fb943075a28>
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python interactive interpreter keeps a reference to the last result in the [`_` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python). Your object is still alive.

Run another expression to clear it:

```
>>> class Foo():
...    def __init__(self):
...       print "Hello"
...    def __del__(self):
...       print "Goodbye"
... 
>>> Foo()
Hello
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x100651ef0>
>>> _
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x100651ef0>
>>> 'Hello world!'
Goodbye
'Hello world!'
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Sneaky interpreter, hoarding references!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Done. I've been lurking on this site for years, never needed to ask a question until today. I need to learn how to use it now!