# Iterate over list of tuples and unpack first elements only

Tags: python, list-comprehension, iterable-unpacking

Assume the following list: `foo = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]`

Is there a way to iterate over the list and unpack the first two elements of the inner tuple only?

This is a usual pattern: `{a: b for a, b, _, _ in foo}`, but this breaks if `foo` is modified (program change) and the tuple now contains 5 elements instead of 4 (the the list comprehension would need to be modified accordingly). I really like to name the elements instead of calling `{f[0]: f[1] for f in foo}`, so ideally, there would be some sort of "absorb all not unpacked variable", so one could call `{a: b for a, b, absorb_rest in foo}`. If that's possible, it wouldn't matter how many elements are contained in the tuple (as long as there are at least 2).

Comment: what do you want your result to look like?

Comment: In the example above: `{1: 2, 5: 6}`, but that's just an example. I'd like to extract the first two elements from the tuples, so for instance, if I were to look for `[a + b for a, b, _, _ in foo]`, I would expect `[3, 11]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), where you extract the first two elements of the tuple, and ignore the rest of the elements. Note that this only works for `python3`

```
{a:b for a, b, *c in foo}
```

Comment: `*_` is more idiomatic as others suggest

Comment: Wow. Is that Python 3 specific?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to update at some stage soon anyway. Is there a similar solution for Python 2.7?

Comment: Apologies, you're correct, `pylint` does not mind, i wonder why. i think pycharm would detect this

Comment: @Chris_Rands Using `_` variable triggers complaints by mypy (the strict type-checking linter for Python) anytime it sees you reuse `_` since their "types won't match". So I have stopped using `_`...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), keeping in this way the first two values from the iterable and ignoring the rest:

```
{a: b for a, b, *_ in foo}
# {1: 2, 5: 6}
```

Comment: `a` and `b` are just examples. It's just making the code more readable when the elements are named (`a` and `b` are proxies for readable names ;-)).

Comment: Are you saying that the variable `_` won't contain any value (or even exist) after completing the list comprehension? That would be unusual...

Comment: No, I am not interested in the remaining values (I was just confused by your comment "Otherwise they will be unnecessarily kept in memory"). My understanding is that `*_` and `*c` are equivalent (both are variables) and the last assignment to the variable (last iteration) will be available after the list comprehension.

Comment: @yatu I don't think that's true. `_` is a convention here, I don't believe it is never allocated memory in any circumstance. `a, _ = [1, 2]; print(_)` or (in poor practice) `a = [print(a, _) for a, _ in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]`

Comment: @roganjosh I agree with that. That's where my confusion stems from. `_` or `c` are equivalent and just variable names (`_` is used more often as it's a convention).

Comment: Underscore has other uses beyond the convention here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-the-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python)

Comment: I wasn't ;-) Thanks for that comment @roganjosh.

Comment: Ahh just learnt something new then :)) will clear up the comments @roganjosh devesh

Comment: Yes of course @roganjosh agreed :) besides it can indeed lead to some confusion  being simply a convention (as in my own case)

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
dict_ = {a:b for a,b, *_ in foo}
```

**Output** :

```
{1: 2, 5: 6}
```

If `foo` is changed to `[(1, 2, 3, 4,9,0), (5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 16)]` by program later, `dict_` still remains : `{1: 2, 5: 6}`

Answer (score 0):

use `lambda`

```
foo = [(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8)]
output = list(map(lambda x:{x[0]:x[1]}, foo))
print(output)
```

output

```
[{1: 2}, {5: 6}]
```