# How do I reset the underscore in an interactive session?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I have overriden the underscore variable `_` in the Python interactive interpreter. How can I make the underscore work again without restarting the interpreter?

Comment: `_` is just a throwaway variable or placeholder. Its value will be overwritten as you continue to use it.

Comment: @MattDMo I would've thought the same thing, but I just tried it in an interpreter and it very much does not rewrite once shadowed. wjandrea's answer is correct.

Comment: @MattDMo In this context, it's actually "the result of the last evaluation" and it's exposed by the interactive interpreter as a builtin. I wrote an answer with the solution.

Comment: Related (more broad): [Is the single underscore "_" a built-in variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538832/4518341)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
del _
```

A global `_` [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `_`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), so deleting the global reveals the builtin again.

---

It's also worth noting that it doesn't actually stop working, it's just not accessible. You can import [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins) to access it:

```
>>> _ = 'foobar'
>>> 22
22
>>> _
'foobar'
>>> import builtins
>>> 23
23
>>> builtins._
23
```